# How to move a task from the tasklist to mytask in my app when I click on the accept Button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a Fragment navigation bar with showing: "Task List", "My Tasks" and "Gallery".
I am using a RecyclerView with CardViews for my Task List.

When I click on some tasks from the Task List, it opens a new Activity with the description of that Task and with an "Accept" Button.

My goal is that when I click on Accept on some task, that task goes to "My Task".

I am new to Android development and don't have much experience with Java, too.